# How do I make VS Code indent access specifiers down in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

How can I make my VS Code indent my access specifiers down like in regular VS Community?

When I type in this:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    public:
    void bar();
};
```

I want this:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    void bar();
};
```

...But it doesn't do that. How can I make it do that?